# Docker windows container having multiple drives

Tags: docker, windows-container

Can I configure a windows container image to have two local NTFS drives ?

I want to test some USN journal functions and I need a local NTFS drive different from the system drive.

Comment: What do you mean? You can map volumes into windows container as you wish from local file system

Comment: @GregorySuvalian The mapped volumes are recognized as mapped network drives by the hosted system.  This means I cannot read or change the NTFS USN journal.